# Add a new line in a variable using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to add a new line in a variable after certain number of words. For example: If we have a variable:

```
$x = "This a variable, start a new line here, This is a new line.";
```

If I print the above variable

```
print $x;
```

I should get the below output:

```
This is a variable,  
start a new line here,  
This is a new line.
```

How can I achieve this in Perl from the variable itself?

Comment: Any ideas to share?  Did you try anything?  It is all _much_ better when you show your attempts and code.   It is also much easier for people to help you more effectively.

Comment: You say start a new line after a certain number of words, then show adding a newline after 4 words and then again after 5 words.  What is the rule you are using?

Comment: Text::Wrap . . . .

Comment: @Kamal: What is *syn*? Please use proper English. Why is your comment different from what **ysth** wrote?

Comment: @Borodin: That's a typo, I wanted to write "sync", I don't see any link to edit it, may be due to less reputations. Anyway, thanks for bringing into notice.

Comment: @Kamal: *synchronisation* or perhaps *synch* would be better. If you're so pressed for time then don't post. You can edit comments for only five minutes.

Comment: @Borodin: Man, better to discuss about the problem, rather than my English, I might be wrong.

By the way, I just googled, "sync" and "synch" both are used, I prefer former.

Comment: @Kamal: I apologise. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sync) presumes *sync*, and *synch* is an alternative. But I disagree that I should ignore all poor English: there are already too many unintelligible posts for *Stack Overflow* to form a reliable concensus.

Comment: @Borodin Ironically... `s/concensus/consensus/`

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree to the formula "after certain number of words".
Note that the first target line has 4 words, whereas remaining 2 have
5 words each.

Actually you need to replace each comma and following sequence of
spaces (if any) with a comma and `\n`.

So the intuitive way to do it is:

```
$x =~ s/,\s*/,\n/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to split the string on `comma followed by a space` and then 
join the word groups with a `comma followed by a newline`.

```
my $x = "This a variable, start a new line here, This is a new line.";

print join(",\n", split /, /, $x) . "\n";
```

**output**

```
This a variable,
start a new line here,
This is a new line.
```

---

For solving the general, `how do I reformat this string with line breaks after n-columns?` problem, use the [Text::Wrap](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Wrap.html) library (as suggested by @ikegami):

```
use Text::Wrap;

my $x = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

$Text::Wrap::columns = 15;

# wrap() needs an array of words
my @words = split /\s+/, $x;

# Initial tab, subsequent tab values set to '' (think indent amount)
print wrap('', '', @words) . "\n";
```

**output**

```
The quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy dog.
```